# Expected format for validation errors in Ember Data (using ActiveModel::Serializers)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

Unfortunately, ActiveModel::Serializers does not currently support validation errors, though they're scheduled for [1.0](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/7). Until then, I've got to hack a solution of my own. The big problem? I have no idea what format Ember Data's ActiveModelAdapter expects these errors to be in. I tried simply passing in the `errors` property, but Ember Data didn't pick up on it:

```
class MySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :errors
end
```

So what should I pass in instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this method to render validation errors (note that you don't use the serializer at all):

```
def render_validation_errors errors
  render json: {errors: errors.to_h}, status: 422
end
```

You would use it like this:

```
def create
  model = Model.new model_params
  if model.save
    respond_with model
  else
    render_validation_errors model.errors
  end
end
```

The format expected by ActiveModelAdapter is:

```
{"errors":{"title":"should begin with a capital letter"}}
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. You have no idea how much time I've spent trying to figure that out. For others, in case `to_h` is undefined for you, try `to_hash`. Not sure why it was failing for me, it's suppose to be supported in Ruby 2.0.